# Where is the first destruction come from?

Tags: c++

I was trying to practice on the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
   virtual void f(){cout<<"A"<<endl;}
   virtual ~A(){cout<<"destruct A"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
   A o1,o2;
   vector <A > O;
   O.push_back(o1);
   cout<<"1"<<endl;
   O.push_back(o2);

cout<<"test"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The results turned out to be:

```
1
destruct A
test
destruct A
destruct A
destruct A
destruct A
```

Get confused about where the first destructor comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After we had print statements to the copy constructor we get this:

```
constructor A(0x7fff6e21e800)
constructor A(0x7fff6e21e7f8)
copy A(0x10e700910: From 0x7fff6e21e800)
1
copy A(0x10e700920: From 0x10e700910)
copy A(0x10e700928: From 0x7fff6e21e7f8)
destruct A(0x10e700910)
test
destruct A(0x10e700920)
destruct A(0x10e700928)
destruct A(0x7fff6e21e7f8)
destruct A(0x7fff6e21e800)
```

So now lets look at the code:

```
int main()
{
   A o1,
     // constructor A(0x7fff6e21e800)
         o2;
     // constructor A(0x7fff6e21e7f8)
   vector <A > O;
   O.push_back(o1);
     // copy A(0x10e700910: From 0x7fff6e21e800)
   cout<<"1"<<endl;
     // 1

   O.push_back(o2);
    // copy A(0x10e700920: From 0x10e700910)    // O needs to expand.
                                                // So a new range is created and the old value
                                                // copied from the old range to the new range.

                                                // Now we push o2 into the vector
    // copy A(0x10e700928: From 0x7fff6e21e7f8)

                                                // Now the old range has to be destroyed.
    // destruct A(0x10e700910)


   cout<<"test"<<endl;
    // test


   return 0;
                 // Before we exit destroy the old vector (of two items)
    // destruct A(0x10e700920)
    // destruct A(0x10e700928)

                // Now destroy o2 then o1
    // destruct A(0x7fff6e21e7f8)
    // destruct A(0x7fff6e21e800)
}
```

Comment: Don't understand why " O needs to expand. So a new range is created and the old value copied from the old range to the new range."

Comment: When `O` was first created it was probably created with a capacity of 1. After the first element was pushed it is now full. But vector will automatically expand and when it does it must copy all the elements from the old data range to the new data range. If you call `O.reseve()` before you start pushing elements then this extra copy will disappear.

Answer (score 5):

Your vector reallocated its memory buffer on the second call to push_back.  This required the object that was in there to be copied to the new buffer, and the original object was destroyed.

If you call `O.reserve(2)` before you insert any objects, that will give your vector enough space to accomadate both objects.  So it shouldn't need to reallocate, and you should not see any destructions before the end of main. Technically there could be more destructions, if your compiler sucks and makes unnecessary copies.  However, from what you've shown so far, it doesn't appear to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Make the constructor and destructor print the memory address of the object, so you can follow it's lifetime:

```
virtual void f() { cout << "A: " << std::hex << this << endl; }
virtual ~A(){ cout << "destruct A: " << std::hex << this << endl; }
```

Comment: You will need to also to do the copy constructor.